# Given the output of cProfile on an arbitrary python program, can one reconstruct the original source code?

Tags: python, profiling, cprofile

If I do something like

`python -m cProfile -o profile.prof myprogram.py`

Can one reconstruct the source code from have access to `profile.prof`?

Comment: No, all you get are the function call points.

Comment: That's what I figured, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All the `.prof` file contains is a [`marshal` serialisation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/marshal.html) of the very same stats you see when you don't use `-o` (and thus print the stats).

It's basically a dictionary keyed on function 'label', with per function call stats, aggregated. A function label is defined as:

```
def label(code):
    if isinstance(code, str):
        return ('~', 0, code)    # built-in functions ('~' sorts at the end)
    else:
        return (code.co_filename, code.co_firstlineno, code.co_name)
```

So only the filename, line number and function name are recorded, nothing else. You can't reconstruct a full program from this.